"Completeness" of absolute values induced by Haar measure
Let $\mu$ be a Haar measure on a non-discrete locally compact field $\mathbb K$. For every $y\in\mathbb K$, define $|y|=\frac{\mu(yE)}{\mu(E)}$ for any Borel measurable set $E$ of positive finite measure. Define $B_r(x)=\{y\in\mathbb K:|y-x|\leq r\}$. Prove that for every $r>0,x_0\in\mathbb K$, there exists $y_0\in\mathbb K$ such that $B_r(x_0)=x_0+y_0B_1(0)$.
I already know that $|\cdot|:\mathbb K\longrightarrow\mathbb R_{\geq0}$ is continuous with the following properties:

$|y|=0$ if and only if $y=0$;
|xy|=|x||y| for all $x,y\in\mathbb K$;
there is a constant $C>0$ such that $|x+y|\leq C(|x|+|y|)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb K$.

I also know that $B_r(x)$ is compact for all $r\geq0, x\in\mathbb K$.
But no matter what I cannot prove that for every $r$ there is some $|y|=r$. Is there a condition missing? Or is there something I couldn't see out of given conditions?

There does not need to be a $y$ with $|y| = r$, but if you take $y$ with $|y| \leq r$ maximal (why does this exist?), it should work

Have you ever worked with an example of a locally compact field besides $\mathbf R$ or $\mathbf C$? The simplest such example, the $p$-adic numbers, only has integral powers of $p$ as values of $|y|$ when $y \not= 0$.

@leoli1 Thanks! I already proved that there exists $r^\prime\leq r$ such that $r^\prime=|y_0|$ for some $y_0\in\mathbb K$ and $B_r(0)=B_{r^\prime}(0)$, but somehow didn't connect the dots.
